# programmatic menu creation using jquery ui

Tags: jquery, user-interface, contextmenu

I would like to create a context menu using jquery ui.

Here is the behavior:

> on hover show the populated context menu.

How can I implement this?  Assume that i do not have a place holder on the dom.  I have only the x,y coordinate of where the hover event happened.

based on the documentation on the jquery ui site, there is only the markup way of creating the menu.  http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/

Answer (score 1):

keep the menu hidden capture the mouse coordinates on `hover` event on a specific location and show the menu and hide it again on `mouseout` from the area and menu

A [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/rsw4S/1/) to get you started